# Choosing object binder in action signature

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, action, method-signature, defaultmodelbinder, custom-model-binder

I have a custom model binder to get data from session, but I also would like to use the default binder from time to time.

Is it possible to choose model binder in action signature instead of using UpdateModel?

Example

```
public ViewResult MyAction(Cart useSessionBinder, Cart useFormData)
{}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`[ModelBinder]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinderattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(
    [ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomModelBinder))] Cart useSessionBinder, 
    Cart useFormData
)
{
    ...
}
```

Obviously you should have not assigned globally your custom model binder to the `Cart` class in your `Application_Start`, otherwise it will automatically apply to all instances of `Cart` appearing as action parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can keep global custom model binder in Appliaction_Start, to let it work everywhere, and reset back to default binder from time to time, when needed

```
public ActionResult MyAction(
       [ModelBinder(typeof(DefaultModelBinder))]  Cart useFormData)
```